# showing image in printf format

Tags: php, image, printing, printf

Im trying to show an image on my website trough the printf command. But i keep getting the errors

```
" class="breadcrumb-right-img"> 
" class="breadcrumb-left-img">
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    if( $settings['breadcrumb_img']['url'] ) :
        printf('<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="breadcrumb-right-img">',$settings['breadcrumb_img']['url'], $settings['breadcrumb_title']);
    endif;
?>
<?php
    if( $settings['breadcrumb_left_img']['url'] ) :
        printf('<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="breadcrumb-left-img">', $settings['breadcrumb_left_img']['url'], $settings['breadcrumb_title']);
    endif;
?>
```

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: By itself that code should work, so the issue is probably something to do with th code above these lines, probably something to do with mixed up quotes

Comment: this could also be caused by your alt text containing a quote.